# How to format properly in TCPDF or FPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf

I am working on mysql data to pdf conversion & I have to print only one column data in table format that means each cell have that one column result

I want to achieve the following format

[format one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsgoD.png)

[format two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRe37.png)

This is my output which is not desired:

[image: My Output]

I tried both **FPDF** and **TCPDF** but I am not able to convert the result in desired format.

## 1.FPDF

```
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$result = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING( `V_REGISTRATION_NO` , 1, 4 ) AS V_SUB_REGISTRATION_NO FROM `tbl_vehicle` WHERE V_STATUS_CAUGHT = 'false' AND V_BANK_ID='1' AND V_BRANCH_ID='1' ORDER BY `V_REGISTRATION_NO` ASC ");
$header = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='poniyaag_new'
AND `TABLE_NAME`='tbl_vehicle'
AND COLUMN_NAME='V_REGISTRATION_NO'
");

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
foreach($header as $heading) {
    foreach($heading as $column_heading)
        $pdf->Cell(60,12,$column_heading,1);
    }
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
        $pdf->Ln();
        foreach($row as $column)
            $pdf->Cell(65,12,$column,1);
    }
}
$pdf->Output();
```

## 2.TCPDF

```
ob_start();
require_once('tcpdf/examples/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL) ; ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if(!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("poniyaag_new");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING( `V_REGISTRATION_NO` , 1, 4 ) AS V_SUB_REGISTRATION_NO FROM `tbl_vehicle` WHERE V_STATUS_CAUGHT = 'false' AND V_BANK_ID='1' AND V_BRANCH_ID='1' ORDER BY `V_REGISTRATION_NO` ASC");
if( ( $result ) ){

    $html = '';
    $html .= "<table width='width: 638px;' border='1px'><tr>";
    if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ){

        $i = 0;

        while( $i < mysql_num_fields( $result ) ){
            $html .= "<th>". mysql_field_name($result, $i) . "</th>";
            $i++;
        }

        $html .= "</tr>";
        $html .= "<tr>";

        while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ){
            foreach ($rows as $data){
                $html .= "<td align='center'>". $data . "</td>";
            }
            // $html.="</tr>";
        }

    }else{

        $html .= "<tr><td colspan='" . ($i+1) . "'>No Results found!</td></tr>";

    }

    $html .= "</table>";
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    // Set various pdf options
    $pdf->SetAuthor('John Doe');
    // etc.
    // Now output the html
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0);
    // Output the PDF to the browser
    ob_end_clean();
    $pdf->Output('somefile.pdf', 'D'); // the second option D forces the browser to download the PDF. Passing I will tell the browser to show it inline.

}else{
    echo "Error in running query :". mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Show us your output file also.

Comment: @Yash my output image is added

Comment: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm you can try this @Ssangeet

Comment: @Yash that is different output format,i have to print only one column result & repeat it in all the other cells.please check the format i added into the question with format 1 & format 2

Comment: did that solve your problem?

Comment: @Trix i will tell you later,actually i solved it before you posted here but i will definitely try your suggested method.

Answer (score 0):

in **TCPDF** You should change this part of your snippet:

```
$html .= "<tr>";
while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ){
    foreach ($rows as $data){
        $html .= "<td align='center'>". $data . "</td>";
    }
    // $html.="</tr>";
}
```

into this:

```
$i = 0;
while( $rows = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ){
    foreach ($rows as $data){
        if( 0 == $i % 5 )
            $html .= "<tr><td align='center'>". $data . "</td>";
        elseif( 4 == $i % 5 )
            $html .= "<td align='center'>". $data . "</td></tr>";
        else
            $html .= "<td align='center'>". $data . "</td>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```